# String index of Difference between two Strings

Tags: java, string, compare

I have two String Lists just like below:

List1 (Generated by sql resultset)

```
10001
10100
10001
```

List2 (Generated by sql resultset)

```
10000
10000
10000
```

Button Action;

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            createList1();
            createList2();
            difference();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }       
    }
```

difference void;

```
public void difference (){
       int minLen = Math.min(List1.get(0).length(), List2.get(0).length());
        for (int i = -1 ; i != minLen ; i++) {
          char chA = List1.get(0).charAt(i);
          char chB = List2.get(0).charAt(i);
        if (chA != chB) {
        System.out.println(chA);
        }
       }  
    }
```

I want to find which index numbers are different in List1 for index 0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `i == -1` is not a valid index. You cannot call `charAt(i)` and pass `-1` as the argument, because that would trigger an exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a loop that iterates the index `i` from zero the length of the shorter of the two strings, and compare characters one by one, using the `==` operator:

```
int minLen = Math.min(a.length(), b.length());
for (int i = 0 ; i != minLen ; i++) {
    char chA = a.charAt(i);
    char chB = b.charAt(i);
    if (chA != chB) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Before starting the comparison you need to check that `a` and `b` are not `null`. Otherwise, getting the length is going to trigger a null reference exception.

Comment: I like this method. But i receive null exception when i compare values. Let me edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public List<Integer> findDiffIndexes(String s1, String s2 ) {
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for( int i = 0; i < s1.length() && i < s2.length(); i++ ) {
        if( s1.charAt(i) != s2.charAt(i) ) {
            indexes.add( i );
        }
    }
    return indexes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#difference%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

> public static String difference(String str1,
>                                   String str2)
>
> Compares two Strings, and returns the portion where they differ. (More precisely, return the remainder of the second String, starting
>   from where it's different from the first.)
>
> For example, difference("i am a machine", "i am a robot") -> "robot".
>
> ```
>  StringUtils.difference(null, null) = null
>  StringUtils.difference("", "") = ""
>  StringUtils.difference("", "abc") = "abc"
>  StringUtils.difference("abc", "") = ""
>  StringUtils.difference("abc", "abc") = ""
>  StringUtils.difference("ab", "abxyz") = "xyz"
>  StringUtils.difference("abcde", "abxyz") = "xyz"
>  StringUtils.difference("abcde", "xyz") = "xyz"
>
>
> Parameters:
>     str1 - the first String, may be null
>     str2 - the second String, may be null 
> Returns:
>     the portion of str2 where it differs from str1; returns the empty String if they are equal
> Since:
>     2.0
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Do loop on List 1 and List2, and compare index value like,
I assume you that both list has same size so,

```
for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++)
{
  if(!list1.get(i).equals(list2.get(i))
   {
     System.out.println("Not equal value of Index="+i);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two Strings will always be the same length...

```
String first = "10000";
String second = "10101";

ArrayList differentIndexes = new ArrayList();

for(int i=0; i<first.length(); i++){
if(first.charAt(i)!=second.charAt(i)){
differentIndexes.add(i);
}
}
```